# Does IntelliJ IDEA have an "add maven dependency" wizard like Eclipse and NetBeans?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

NetBeans and Eclipse have nice little wizards which allow me to search local and remote Maven repositories and add any dependency correctly to my POM.

Does IntelliJ (community edition) support anything of this sort?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `pom.xml` press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>. In the small pop-up click on `Dependency`.

[image]

There you can search any artifact or class. It looks like:

[image]

You also need to make sure that the local and remote repositories you are using have been indexed by IntelliJ. That can easily be done in `Settings` -> `Maven` -> `Repositories` (more details [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-repositories.html))

Comment: Nice! It looks just like what I was looking for. However, it seems to contain a very small set of available artifacts. E.g. I can't find Guava or EasyMock in it. What gives?

Comment: I searched both and it worked! Are you sure that your repositories are setup correctly?

Comment: Well, it's a fresh install of Maven, I haven't changed `settings.xml` at all yet, which should imply that at least the central repository should be set up correctly. Funny thing is - Guava is even in my local repo and IntelliJ still can't find it.

Comment: @Zoltán That is indeed weird! I'll check and see if there is anything else I can find

Comment: @Zoltán Have you checked in `Settins` -> `Maven` -> `Repositories` to see what repositories are indexed?

Comment: I also just realized that my remote repo said that it was **never** indexed, and my local repository was last indexed yesterday. It solved the problem. Thanks a lot! Perhaps you could update your answer and add this information as a note.